# Google Play Store Source code

Tags: android, google-play

I am looking for google play source code I have seen some other app store like cafebazaar.ir which have an app like google play store. Are they using google play store source code or something else.

Comment: I'm certain that Google Play Store is close-sourced by Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Google Play Store Source code is not published. The app you mention can be that uses the Google design principles: https://developer.android.com/intl/es/design/index.html